# How to keep CheckBox value after a get?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

In my  ASP.NET MVC 5 website i have this situation:

I have a GridView that i can get just the default rows or all the rows(including the deleted ones). Im trying to control that using a CheckBox in the ribbon of the view called 'cbxGetAll'.

So, here is my script:

```
<script>
function OnCommandExecuted(s, e) {
     if (e.item.name == "cbxGetAll") {
        if (e.parameter) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index",new {getAll = true})';
            return;

        } else {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index",new {getAll = false})';
            return;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

And my Action:

```
  public ActionResult Index(bool? getAll)
  {
       if (getAll != null && (bool) getAll)
       {
          //Return Without Filter
       }
       else
       {
          //Return With Filter
       }
  }
```

I change the getAll parameter in the URL and it works well.
But the problem is that when the ActionResult completes, it reloads the page (of course) and then i lost the checkbox state.
How can i deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about view models.  You should be returning a view model that has the value of your checkbox, and have your view use that value.  If you are also returning data, simply place the data (whatever it is) inside your view model as well.

Example:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public bool GetAll { get; set; }

    public SomeDataModel[] MyData { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(bool? getAll)
{
   SomeDataModel[] data;

   if (getAll != null && (bool) getAll)
   {
      var data = GetSomeData(true);
   }
   else
   {
      var data = GetSomeData(false);
   }

   return View(new MyViewModel() { MyData = data, GetAll = getAll == true });
}
```